# Sub SQL Query to gather distinct logins

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve a list of users that have logged in within the last 7 days and the count they've logged in, given the following (stripped down for simplicity) tables:

```
+-------------------+     +-----------------------------+
|       users       |     |         event_logs          |
+-------------------+     +-----------------------------+
|  id  |   name     |     | user  | event  | created_at |
+-------------------+     +-----------------------------+
|   1  | Jake       |     |   1   | login  |     date   |
|   2  | Jenny      |     |   2   | login  |     date   |
|   3  | Polly      |     |   2   | login  |     date   |
+-------------------+     |   2   | login  |     date   |
                          |   1   | login  |     date   |
                          |   3   | login  |     date   |
                          |   3   | login  |     date   |
                          |   1   | login  |     date   |
                          +-----------------------------+
```

So far, I have been able to join the two tables and access the login lines, but the results contain duplicates and no counts.

```
SELECT u.name, e.created_at
FROM event_logs e
INNER JOIN users u ON e.user = u.id
WHERE e.event = "login" 
AND DATE(e.created_at) >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
ORDER BY u.id;
```

So I tried to make a sub-query but running `select * FROM ( <<THAT QUERY ABOVE>>) logins;` returns a syntax error :

Comment: You have to use `GROUP BY`. You can find plenty of posts here in SO exhibiting the functionality of `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

First, value should be wrap with single quote. You also don't need a subquery to count the number of instances the user have logged in. You can directly use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT u.name, 
       COUNT(e.created_at) AS TOTAL_COUNT
FROM   event_logs e
       INNER JOIN users u ON e.user = u.id
WHERE  e.event = 'login'
       AND DATE(e.created_at) >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
GROUP  BY u.name
```